# iPhone/iPad unique identifier BESIDES UUID/UDID?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, udid

The project I am on is requesting two (or even three) unique identifiers from the iPhone or iPad.  I know, I know... the UDID should be enough but we are trying to see if there are any other unique identifiers that we can use.

I can get the IMEI, serial number, MAC Address, etc. from the phone using the IOKit.framework but apparently this is frowned upon by Apple and any app using this framework will be rejected.

Does anyone have any other ideas, or identifiers that I am missing that could be used?

Thanks!

Comment: You could always hash the UUID in some cryptic way to get two more IDs :)

Comment: @Nick:  I don't think the OP wants to use the UDID in any way because it is easy to fake that, e.g. Download UDIDFaker from Cydia on a jailbroken device.

Comment: Apple frowns upon IMEI?  That's not good, because it restricts so much of what that value is good for.

Comment: ...because not every iOS device has an IMEI.

Comment: If you want a unique id, have the user create one.

Comment: Do you need to identify the user or the device? Remember people sell their phones or buy new ones all the time. Using any kind of device-specific ID will not help you track users.

Comment: @edcincy Do you know that UUID and UDID are completely different and unrelated things? A UDID is a 40 hexadecimal digit number, and UUID has 32 hex digits. A UDID is specific to iOS devices. UUID is a generic concept used in countless technologies and scenarios. Conflating the two makes your question confusing, as UUIDs are often used as a replacement for Apple's now-deprecated UDIDs.

Answer (score 8):

This question is old however a new unique, vendor based, identifier has now been added to replace the deprecated UUID in iOS 6.

The [`[UIDevice identifierForVendor]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) should now be used instead of [`[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/uniqueIdentifier) which is now deprecated as of iOS 5.0

Example usage:

```
NSUUID *uuid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
NSString *uuidString = [uuid UUIDString];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the ICCID and the IMSI (if they exist).

```
NSString *commcenter = @"/private/var/wireless/Library/Preferences/com.apple.commcenter.plist";
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:commcenter];
NSString *ICCID = [dict valueForKey:@"ICCID"];
NSString *IMSI = [dict valueForKey:@"IMSI"];
```

I think that's as far as you will get. I don't know any other options for getting an universal ID.

> UPDATE 2013-03-13:
>   This has probably changed since I wrote this answer almost two years ago. I don't even remember what was the iOS version at the moment. Also as @joshis correctly pointed out in the comments "You cannot legally do this, since your app would read stuff from outside the application sandbox and therefore, it will be rejected, as specified in AppStore Review Guidelines...".

Comment: What exactly does "legally" mean?  Will the app be rejected for capturing these?

Comment: No, you cannot legally do this, since your app would read stuff from outside the application sandbox and therefore, it will be rejected, as specified in AppStore Review Guidelines, 2.6: apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected

Comment: I can't open such directory: "wireless" in /private/var/wireless/Library/Preferences/com.apple.commcenter.plist. I'm trying to do that on non-jailbroken device

Comment: This has probably changed since I wrote this answer almost two years ago. I don't even remember what was the iOS version at the moment.

Comment: I need the ICCID for an enterprise distribution application. When I try the above code, I'm getting null for the ICCID. Any idea how I can actually get it on iOS 6?

Answer (score 3):

From Apple:

> The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another
>   app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value
>   **changes** when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the
>   device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them.

So if you use `[UIDevice identifierForVendor]` and the user delete the app and reinstall it, the id will be different(so no real physical device tracking)

Why don't you use `SecureUDID`?

```
NSString *domain = @"com.example.app";
NSString *key = @"mykey";
NSString *udid = [SecureUDID UDIDForDomain:domain usingKey:key];
```

This way, even if the user delete the app and reinstall it, the UDID will be same. This will give you consistent tracking(or whatever you want to do with the UDID).
Btw, the above is still permitted from Apple.
Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

The method for getting the UDID is being deprecated, you should now use `CFUUIDCreate` which I think could be used multiple times to get more identifiers if needed

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should clarify your question.

> requesting two (or even three) unique identifiers from the iPhone or iPad

…is a contradiction in terms. If your purpose is to track a specific physical device, then a single unique identifier, by definition, is enough. That’s what *unique* means.

Perhaps, what you really want is to track multiple things about each user’s use of your app, as opposed to the device. Say your networked game app allows the user 1, 2, or 3 different personalities. As they user creates a distinct personality, you must track each of that user's personalities amongst all the other user’s personalities.

For this kind of purpose, generating and storing a [UUID*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) is a proper and common solution. iOS includes libraries to generate a UUID value. The only catch is that if the user deletes and re-installs the app, the storage of that UUID may be lost. There are workarounds for this challenge, which you may learn about by googling for discussions of replacing UDID tracking with generated UUID values.

---

This question is a bit older. So I should mention: In iOS 5, Apple [deprecated](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/09/ask-ars-whats-the-big-deal-with-iphone-udids/) the use of the UDID. As of 2013-05-01 Apple is [rejecting](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=3212013a) any app that accesses the UDID.

---

(*) Do not confuse a UUID with a UDID. UUID is a [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122) 128-bit (32 hex digits) number often used as a virtually unique identifier in many technology scenarios. UDID is Apple's 40 hex digit string burned into every iOS device to uniquely identify each device.

Answer (score 1):

DeviceCheck API in iOS 11 is an interesting solution to get unique Identifier, the advantage it has is - the value will be retained even after the app in uninstalled. So use cases like trial installation and rewards can be effectively controlled by developers.