# What is the difference between uuid ,udid and device token in ios stack overflow

Tags: objective-c

I googled it but every one says difference between UUID and UDID. but i am looking for difference between uuid,udid and device token in iOS

Can any one help me simple and short

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone/iPad unique identifier BESIDES UUID/UDID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599471/iphone-ipad-unique-identifier-besides-uuid-udid)

Comment: I already saw that link but there is no information regarding device token. the thing is i want know the difference between 3(UUID,UDID and Device Token).that's the reason only i posted.

Answer (score 7):

**UUID (Universally Unique IDentifier)** A UUID is an identifier created using a standard algorithm, as described in [RFC 4122](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) (and its predecessors).  UUIDs are used for all sort of purposes, including the folder name for app installs on iOS.  Other common uses include request ids for network requests, unique identifiers for objects such as accounts, messages, groups or whatever an app deals with.  One benefit of such identifiers is that they are statistically unique, which allows them to be generated by one device and used by any other with little or no fear of collisions.  This has great benefits for networked apps.

**UDID (Unique Device Identifier)** A number in each iPhone that is used by developers to distribute new apps directly into the phone for testing purposes before they are available in the App Store. The UDIDs are used to create an Apple-certified provisioning file that is dragged with the app into iTunes.

The UDID is not visible on the phone. It has to be revealed in iTunes, and it cannot be highlighted and copied like normal text. To retrieve the UDID you would need to do the following:

Connect your iPad to your computer, and run iTunes.
Select your device in the 'Device' list. On the right side, you'll see information about your device.
Click the Serial Number. It will switch to displaying your UDID.
Press Cmd-C to copy the UDID to your clipboard.

UDIDs are also available in the Devices window in Xcode.  It is the `Identifier` field, which is available after selecting the device in the list on the left-hand side.

**Device Token** - An identifier for the Apple Push Notification System for iOS devices. Each device has two device tokens – one for development, and one for production (ad hoc or app store builds). The tokens are 64 hexadecimal characters.

Comment: `UUID` is not an app thing at all, never mind a "per app" thing.  `UUID` is an identifier created via one of several standard processes, as outlined in one or more RFCs.  They can be used for anything where such an identifier is required:  Primary keys in a database table, file names, account identifiers, etc.  (Usage as a PK may not be optimal, but it's possible.)

Comment: The `UDID` is also available from the Devices window in Xcode, where the value is copyable, just like any other text field.